# ASP.NET HttpModule gives "Connection Reset" in browser

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I have implemented a HttpModule in ASP.NET (framework 2.0).

From my logging on the server, I can see that the http request is being picked up by my HttpModule, and my code runs successfully (writing content back to the Response stream).

However, the web browser (IE, FF, Chrome, all the same) just give me a "connection reset" error message.

I've checked the Event Log on the server; there are no related errors or messages there.

**EXTRA INFO:** When I use the "Live HTTP Headers" plugin in FF, it does not even display my client request (although I am sure it reaches the server, due to the request being captured in the server log).

How can I troubleshoot what's happening here?

Comment: @Alex: Well, that's the problem, my code appears to be running just fine (based on my log output, plus I have this running fine on another server). It's the IIS side of things that seems to be wrong. Maybe this is a question for ServerFault instead...

Comment: Can you access any other aspx/html pages on this IIS?

Comment: @Alex: I can access static files (such as images) on the same IIS, in different folders. My app folder, the one with the HttpModule, gives "connection reset". See also info about Live HTTP Headers above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering my own question here... I found out that there is a log file at C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.

It shows the following:

```
2010-08-26 12:07:10 xx.xx.xx.xx 2618 xx.xx.xx.xx 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /web/myapp - 232667915  Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2010-08-26 12:07:10 xx.xx.xx.xx 2624 xx.xx.xx.xx 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /web/myapp - 232667915 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
2010-08-26 12:07:10 xx.xx.xx.xx 2625 xx.xx.xx.xx 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /web/myapp - 232667915 Connection_Dropped DefaultAppPool
```

After googling a bit I found this: http://davidovitz.blogspot.com/2007/08/iis-60-httperr-logs-show.html

And followed the advice:

1. "aspnet_regiis -u"
2. Uninstall IIS
3. Reboot
4. Reinstall IIS
5. "aspnet_regiis -i"

... reconfigure sites, and everything worked beautifully again. :-)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the presence of the HTTPERR folder, in which I found my particular culprit: "Connections_Refused", which according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820729/en-us means "The kernel NonPagedPool memory has dropped below 20MB and http.sys has stopped receiving new connections", and which led us to reboot the affected server.  Yes, reboot is lame (what is this, Windows NT?), but I'm not getting connection reset errors any more.

Comment: Likewise -- that HTTPERR folder is gold, especially that s-reason field.  Mine was simply "verb" but it did explain the TCP Connection Resets that the network guys were complaining about.